# From Express using EJS as view Engine, Can we redirect to a html page with socket.io implementation?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs, passport.js

I implemented socket.io with the following file in a folder.

> app.js,socket.html

I included twitter/Facebook/Google Authentication logic using (Express/Node/passport/EJS) in app.js.Once authentication is successful I am trying to redirect to socket.html to establish socket connection.

```
    app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
       res.redirect('/socket');
    });
    app.get('/socket', function(req, res){ res.redirect('/socket.html'); });
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Since the authentication logic is in Express and uses EJS as view Engine, Is Redirecting the callback to a html page with socket connection possible ?

Socket works fine when its standalone.When I integrate passport.js for Authentication, I face this problem.
The HTML page opens. But I get the following error. [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: Your question is horrifyingly unclear.  Yes; it is possible to send a redirect, even if the URL contains the word `socket`.  Are you having a problem?

Comment: After Authenticating using passport (EJS as view engine) , I want to redirect to HTML page where my socket implementation is.

Comment: OK.  Are you having a problem?

Comment: The HTML page opens. But I get the following error.               [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: That has nothing to do with any of your question.  You need to set up socket.io.

Comment: Socket works fine when its standalone.When I integrate passport.js for Authentication, I face this problem.